# .htaccess rewrite returning content but returns 404 header status

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have some rewrites in my .htaccess file which look like this (I've changed file/var names, but essentially the same):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/pageno=([^/\.]+)?$ page.php?slug=$1&pageno=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/pageno=([^/\.]+)?$ page.php?slug=$1&something=$2&pageno=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1&something=$2
```

When I visit one of the rewritten URLs, such as www.mydomain.com/page/something the correct content from page.php?slug=something is shown in most browsers, except older versions of Internet Explorer, but the real issue is that the rewritten URL returns a 404 header code (probably why some browsers won't show content, and others choose to).

I have other rewrites which seem to work and return 200 OK headers, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-some-page-([^/\.]+).html?$ some-page.php?pageno=$2&myvar=$1
```

The only difference I can see is that the above rewrite includes a fake .html extension, so unsure if this is treated any different.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 header("HTTP/1.0 200");
```

after you header include, so something like

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
header("HTTP/1.0 200");
```